# How to fix nil:NilClass error in polymorphic-associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my comment controller code

```
 private
        def set_commentable
            @commentable = Question.find(params[:question_id])
            @commentable = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
        end
```

I've tried but i'm getting below error, I hope I did error in passing of comment id

```
undefined method `set_comment' for #<CommentsController:0xb34e3348>
```

Comment: in your create action you are getting @commentable value is nill

Comment: You need to set @commentable in your CommentsController

Comment: How to set @commentable  in CommentsController

Comment: I referred this tutorial https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations# Thank you

Comment: @PalPrasanth, could you please add more code like your create action params

Comment: I've updated my code@ Gaurav

Comment: Have you define :set_comment method in private section of your comments_controller, please check as per your code there is no method named "set_comment" in your comments_controller and you are using this method in your filter so that you need to define 'set_comment' in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have set_commentable inside your CommentsController your are getting undefined method error:

```
before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :create]
private

def set_comment
    @commentable = Comment.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79324/discussion-on-answer-by-adnan-devops-undefined-method-comments-for-nilnilclas).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your comments controller

```
 def set_comment
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
 end
```